# Ajax request collapsing multi-level JSON object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, json

Im sending data through `JQuery` `AJAX` to a `python backend server`. When I send the data it changes the object to a different format. Is there a way of stopping this? I've looked online but i'm not 100% whats going on.

Example of data im sending through the request:

```
  data:{
     name:"test",
     products:[
       { name: "test_product", id: 1 },
       { name: "test product2", id: 2 }
     ],
     session_id:"blablabla",
  }
```

How it appears when it comes into the server:

```
  {
     "name":"test",
     "products[0][name]":"test_product",
     "products[0][id]":"1",
     "products[1][name]":"test_product2",
     "products[1][id]":"2",
     "session_id":"blablabla",
  }
```

Comment: You missing comma in your `products` array

Comment: Sorry was an oversight, its just some example data to show what's happening anyway. My actual request object is much larger.

Comment: Show the python code please. There are no issue in javascript.

Comment: FWIW it looks like your json has been treated as form-encoded ???

Comment: Show the JS code too. This is a valid JS object that can be encoded as JSON and sent, but that doesn't mean you did so properly…

Comment: Some code would help, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Data was being sent as form data because i didn't include

```
contentType: 'application/json'
```

In the ajax call. Thanks bruno :)